# Call to a member function getName() on a non-object when creating product programmatically

Tags: magento-1.8

Once the user enters details & click on `Register`, we are creating an account in site successfully, along with this we are trying to create new product Programmatically as we did this successfully when we click on `login` button.

But for `Register` we have an error as below :

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object` in

```
$product->setName($originalProduct->getName());
```

> controllers :

```
protected function _createit()
    {
        // Clear the messages each time we call it
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true);

        if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(),"1.9.2.2",">="))
        {
            // Only from 1.9.2.2
            if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        }

        $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return;
        }

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();

        try {
            $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);

            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(),"1.9.1.0",">="))
                {
                    // Only from 1.9.1.0
                    $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
                }
                $customer->save();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                    array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                );
                $result['redirect'] = $this->_successProcessRegistration($customer);
                $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                 $productId=$this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');

              // code for register end                      

                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

                    /
                    $rand = rand(1, 9999);
                    $product->setTypeId($type) 
                        ->setAttributeSetId(17) 
                        ->setSku('CDSB1_sku' . $rand) / 
                        ->setWebsiteIDs(array(
                        1
                    ));


                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());

                    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();                 

                    return $product;

                    // code for register start
            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $result['error'] = $message;

        } 

        catch (Exception $e) {

           // $result['error'] = $this->__('Cannot save the customer.');
        }


         Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));   

    }
```

> register form :

```
<?php if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect1', 
array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'), 
'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId() )) ?>" 
method="post" id="ajaxlogin-create-form">

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
</form>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: where is `$originalProduct` ?

Comment: you are getting error because there is no `$originalProduct` defined in your controller code

Comment: working well, please post ur answer.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

You are getting an error because there is no `$originalProduct` defined in your controller code.

Just define `$originalProduct` and that will solve your problem.